# custom listview stucks when new item is generting and scrolling

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I have an issue.I have custom listView which has many child and also have another custom listview in it.All data which is display in both listView is coming from database.My Problem is that When I scroll My main ListView it stucks for a while and then scroll.I uploaded My all code here.

**My Main Activity class:**

```
public class TransactionListMonthWise<DisplayYear> extends TopParentActivity {

ListView statement;
ArrayList<DisplayMonth> status;
ArrayList<DisplayYear> yearstatus;
addBankTransactionList mAdapter;
TextView tvBankName, tvBalance, tvBankAccNoForHistory;
String monthname;
String monthName;
int yearName;
String bankname, amount, accno;
Date theDate;
String currencySymbl, cur_sym;
EPreferences epref;
String TotalBalance, BankBalance, finalTotalIncome;
Toolbar toolbarTransactionListMonthWise;
boolean loadingMore = false;
int itemsPerPage = 2;
DisplayMonth monthNameInAdapter;
int month;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaction_monthwise);

    bindview();
    init();
    addListener();
}

private void init() {

    epref = EPreferences.getInstance(TransactionListMonthWise.this);
    getPrefData();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    bankname = intent.getStringExtra("NAME");
    tvBankName.setText(bankname);

    TotalBalance = String.valueOf(intent.getDoubleExtra("BALANCE", 0.0));

    BankBalance = new BigDecimal(TotalBalance).toPlainString();
    DecimalFormat decimalFormatIncome = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
    finalTotalIncome = decimalFormatIncome.format(Double
            .valueOf(TotalBalance));

    tvBalance.setText(currencySymbl
            + " "
            + String.format("%,.00f",
                    (double) Double.parseDouble(finalTotalIncome)));

    // tvBalance.setText(amount + " " + currencySymbl);

    Log.i("symbol", currencySymbl);
    accno = intent.getStringExtra("ACCNO");
    status = new ArrayList<DisplayMonth>();
    yearstatus = new ArrayList<DisplayYear>();
    tvBankAccNoForHistory.setText("xxxxx"
            + intent.getStringExtra("ACC_NUMBER"));
    Utils.BANK_ACC_NUM = intent.getStringExtra("ACC_NUMBER");
    Utils.BANK_NAME_DISP = bankname;
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarTransactionListMonthWise);
    this.toolbarTransactionListMonthWise
            .setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white100);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(bankname + " History");
}

private void bindview() {
    toolbarTransactionListMonthWise = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarTransactionListMonthWise);
    statement = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_transaction_view);
    tvBankName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBankNameForHistory);
    tvBalance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNetBalanceForHistory);
    tvBankAccNoForHistory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBankAccNoForHistory);
}

private void addListener() {

    statement.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        int mLastFirstVisibleItem;
        boolean mIsScrollingUp;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollstate) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount)) {
                new MailSender().execute();
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(TransactionListMonthWise.this,
            BankList.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private String getMonth(int month1) {
    switch (month1) {
    case 1:
        monthname = "Jan";
        break;

    case 2:
        monthname = "Feb";
        break;
    case 3:
        monthname = "Mar";
        break;
    case 4:
        monthname = "Apr";
        break;
    case 5:
        monthname = "May";
        break;
    case 6:
        monthname = "Jun";
        break;
    case 7:
        monthname = "Jul";
        break;
    case 8:
        monthname = "Aug";
        break;
    case 9:
        monthname = "Sep";
        break;
    case 10:
        monthname = "Oct";
        break;
    case 11:
        monthname = "Nov";
        break;
    case 12:
        monthname = "Dec";
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return monthname;
}

private int getYear(int years) {
    switch (years) {
    case 1:
        years = 2011;
        break;

    case 2:
        years = 2012;
        break;
    case 3:
        years = 2013;
        break;
    case 4:
        years = 2014;
        break;
    case 5:
        years = 2015;
        break;
    case 6:
        years = 2016;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return years;
}

private void getPrefData() {
    cur_sym = epref.getPreferencesStr(epref.KEY_CURRENCY, "India");

    Log.d("vaaaaa", " == " + cur_sym);

    if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("India")) {
        currencySymbl = getResources().getString(R.string.India);

    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("US")) {
        currencySymbl = getResources().getString(R.string.United_States);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("Japan")) {
        currencySymbl = getResources().getString(R.string.Japan);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("England")) {
        currencySymbl = getResources().getString(R.string.England_pound);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("Costa Rica")) {
        currencySymbl = getResources().getString(R.string.Costa);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("UK")) {
        currencySymbl = getResources().getString(R.string.United);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("Phillipines")) {
        currencySymbl = getResources().getString(R.string.Philippines);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("Mangolia")) {
        currencySymbl = getResources().getString(R.string.Macedonia);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("Australia")) {
        currencySymbl = getResources().getString(R.string.Australia);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("Europ")) {
        currencySymbl = getResources().getString(R.string.Euro);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class MailSender extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {
    Dialog progress;

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progress = new Dialog(TransactionListMonthWise.this,
                R.style.AppDialogExit);
        progress.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        progress.show();
        progress.setContentView(R.layout.custom_loading_dialog);
        TextView tv = (TextView) progress.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("Mail is sending...");
        progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        final RelativeLayout footerView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loadItemsLayout_recyclerView);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        // int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 10;
        int currentYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        Log.d("viewMonths", "month is" + month + " " + currentYear);

        for (int j = month; j > 0; j--) {

            monthNameInAdapter = new DisplayMonth();
            monthName = getMonth(j);
            monthNameInAdapter.setMonth(monthName);
            status.add(monthNameInAdapter);

        }

        mAdapter = new addBankTransactionList(getApplicationContext(),
                month, status, bankname, accno, currentYear, amount);

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // progress.dismiss();
        if (progress != null) {
            progress.dismiss();
            progress = null;
        }
        try {
            statement.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Main Xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarTransactionListMonthWise"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlBankNameAndBalance"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/green_100"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/main_list_data_disp_padding_left"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/main_list_data_disp_padding_right"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/main_list_data_disp_padding_top" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBankNameForHistory"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconId"
            android:text="@string/BankBalance"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_900"
            android:textSize="@dimen/main_list_data_disp_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBankAccNoForHistory"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvBankNameForHistory"
            android:text="@string/BankBalance"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_500"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNetBalanceForHistory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_900"
            android:textSize="@dimen/main_list_data_disp_text_size" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_transaction_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/loadItemsLayout_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/progress_layout"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

**Main Adapter Class:**

```
public class addBankTransactionList extends BaseAdapter {

// Activity activityCategory;
static ArrayList<DisplayMonth> monthName;
// ArrayList<DisplayYear> yearName;
ArrayList<Expense> expense;
ArrayList<Income> incomes, Arr;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
ArrayList<String> arrDateDebit, arrDateCredit;
ArrayList<Double> arrAmountDebit, arrAmountCredit;
Context contextAddBank;
int CurrentMonth;
String bankNameForMatch, months, allyear, SystemMonthInString, amount,
        bankAccNoForMatch;
int monthname;
String currencySymbl, cur_sym;
String date = "", thirdYear;
String monthNameInString;
EPreferences epref;
ArrayList<Income> tempIncomeses = new ArrayList<Income>();
String dateIncome, dateExpense;
Double expenseAmount, incomeAmount;
DataBaseAdapter adapter;
// private String ;
int monthNameInStringExpense, monthNameInStringIncome;
int yr, year;
int monthsInIntIncome, dateInIntIncome, yearInIntIncome,
        monthsInIntExpense;
String convertDate;
// private ArrayList<Income> tempincomes = new ArrayList<Income>();
List list;
Date date1;
String emptyExpenseAmount, emptyIncomeAmount;
FilterData data;
private String bankname, accno;
public static Boolean isScrolling = true;

public static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvDate, tvIncomeMoney, tvExpenseMoney,
            tvRecordnotFound, tvIncomeSymblIncomeDisp, tvTransactionType,
            tvTransactionDate, tvTransactionAmount, tvMoneyCurrencyExpense,
            tvMoneyCurrencyIncome;
    ListView rvList;

}

public addBankTransactionList(Context mcontext, int month,
        ArrayList<DisplayMonth> status, String bankname, String bankAccNo,
        int year, String amt) {
    super();

    this.contextAddBank = mcontext;
    monthName = status;
    CurrentMonth = month;
    bankNameForMatch = bankname;
    bankAccNoForMatch = bankAccNo;
    yr = year;
    amount = amt;
}

public boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter != null) {

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

        Log.i("TotalRecord", numberOfItems + "");
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            item.measure(0, 0);
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight()
                * (numberOfItems - 1);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
        listView.setClickable(false);
        listView.setEnabled(false);
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void getPrefData() {
    cur_sym = epref.getPreferencesStr(epref.KEY_CURRENCY, "India");

    Log.d("vaaaaa", " == " + cur_sym);

    if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("India")) {
        currencySymbl = contextAddBank.getResources().getString(
                R.string.India);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("US")) {
        currencySymbl = contextAddBank.getResources().getString(
                R.string.United_States);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("Japan")) {
        currencySymbl = contextAddBank.getResources().getString(
                R.string.Japan);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("England")) {
        currencySymbl = contextAddBank.getResources().getString(
                R.string.England_pound);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("Costa Rica")) {
        currencySymbl = contextAddBank.getResources().getString(
                R.string.Costa);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("UK")) {
        currencySymbl = contextAddBank.getResources().getString(
                R.string.United);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("Phillipines")) {
        currencySymbl = contextAddBank.getResources().getString(
                R.string.Philippines);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("Mangolia")) {
        currencySymbl = contextAddBank.getResources().getString(
                R.string.Macedonia);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("Australia")) {
        currencySymbl = contextAddBank.getResources().getString(
                R.string.Australia);
    } else if (cur_sym.equalsIgnoreCase("Europ")) {
        currencySymbl = contextAddBank.getResources().getString(
                R.string.Euro);
    }
}

private int getMonthName(String month1) {
    switch (month1.toLowerCase().toString()) {

    case "Jan":
        monthname = 1;
        break;

    case "Feb":
        monthname = 2;
        break;

    case "Mar":
        monthname = 3;
        break;

    case "Apr":
        monthname = 4;
        break;

    case "May":
        monthname = 5;
        break;

    case "Jun":
        monthname = 6;
        break;

    case "Jul":
        monthname = 7;
        break;

    case "Aug":
        monthname = 8;
        break;

    case "Sep":
        monthname = 9;
        break;

    case "Oct":
        monthname = 10;
        break;

    case "Nov":
        monthname = 11;
        break;

    case "Dec":
        monthname = 12;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return monthname;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return monthName.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View conView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder vh;
    if (conView == null) {
        conView = LayoutInflater.from(contextAddBank).inflate(
                R.layout.transaction_list, null, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.tvDate = (TextView) conView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        vh.rvList = (ListView) conView
                .findViewById(R.id.lvDisplayExpenseList);
        vh.tvIncomeMoney = (TextView) conView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvIncomeMoney);
        vh.tvExpenseMoney = (TextView) conView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvExpenseMoney);
        vh.tvRecordnotFound = (TextView) conView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvrecordnotFound);
        vh.tvIncomeSymblIncomeDisp = (TextView) conView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvIncomeSymblIncomeDisp);
        vh.tvMoneyCurrencyExpense = (TextView) conView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvMoneyCurrencyExpense);
        vh.tvMoneyCurrencyIncome = (TextView) conView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvMoneyCurrencyIncome);
        adapter = new DataBaseAdapter(contextAddBank);
        arrDateDebit = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrAmountDebit = new ArrayList<Double>();
        arrDateCredit = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrAmountCredit = new ArrayList<Double>();
        epref = EPreferences.getInstance(contextAddBank);
        incomes = new ArrayList<Income>();
        expense = new ArrayList<Expense>();

        getPrefData();
        vh.tvMoneyCurrencyExpense.setText(currencySymbl);
        vh.tvMoneyCurrencyIncome.setText(currencySymbl);
        adapter.open();
        adapter.close();
        conView.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) conView.getTag();
    }
    expense.clear();
    incomes.clear();

    arrDateCredit.clear();
    arrAmountCredit.clear();
    arrDateDebit.clear();
    arrAmountDebit.clear();
    adapter.open();
    // viewHolder.rvList.setAdapter(Adapter);
    incomes = adapter.read_income();
    expense = adapter.read_expense();

    double totalExpense = 0.0;
    double totalIncome = 0.0;
    DisplayMonth month = monthName.get(position);
    vh.tvDate.setText(month.getMonth() + "  " + yr);
    months = month.getMonth();

    Log.d("tagNameAdapter",
            "name is " + bankNameForMatch + ":::" + month.getMonth());

    Log.d("expencesize", "size is " + expense.size());

    // expense = adapter.read_expense_with_bankName(bankNameForMatch,
    // bankAccNoForMatch);

    if (expense.size() > 0) {

        for (int l = 0; l < expense.size(); l++) {

            Log.d("tagbankfil",
                    "" + bankNameForMatch + "=="
                            + expense.get(l).getBankname() + " AND "
                            + expense.get(l).getAccno() + "=="
                            + bankAccNoForMatch);

            if (bankNameForMatch.equals(expense.get(l).getBankname())
                    && bankAccNoForMatch.substring(
                            bankAccNoForMatch.length() - 3)
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    expense.get(l)
                                            .getAccno()
                                            .substring(
                                                    expense.get(l)
                                                            .getAccno()
                                                            .length() - 3))) {

                dateExpense = expense.get(l).getDate();
                expenseAmount = expense.get(l).getAmount();

                Log.i("ExpenseAmount", expenseAmount + ":::::"
                        + dateExpense);

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                StringTokenizer tokensIncome = new StringTokenizer(
                        dateExpense, "-");

                String firstDate = tokensIncome.nextToken();
                String secondMonth = tokensIncome.nextToken();
                thirdYear = tokensIncome.nextToken();

                monthsInIntExpense = Integer.parseInt(secondMonth);

                int totalYear = Integer.parseInt(thirdYear);

                Log.i("MonthNameExpense", totalYear + "");

                Log.i("MonthSplitExpense", firstDate + "  " + secondMonth
                        + "  " + thirdYear);

                // for (int jmon = 0; jmon < expense.size(); jmon++) {

                Log.i("loopTimes", "Check");

                SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "dd-MM-yyyy");

                Date dateVal = null;
                Log.i("axisbankdateval", dateVal + "");
                try {
                    dateVal = sdfSource.parse(dateExpense);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "dd-MMM-yyyy");

                convertDate = sdfDestination.format(dateVal);
                String[] parts = convertDate.split("-");
                String transactionMonth = parts[1];
                String transactionYear = parts[2];

                Log.i("allYear", year + "  ");
                monthNameInStringExpense = getMonthName(transactionMonth);

                Log.i("finddate", convertDate + ":::" + transactionMonth
                        + ":::" + monthNameInStringExpense + "::"
                        + transactionYear);

                Log.d("tagmonth", "" + month.getMonth() + " ::: "
                        + transactionMonth + " ---- " + totalYear + "::::"
                        + year);

                if (month.getMonth().contains(transactionMonth)
                        && totalYear == year) {

                    emptyExpenseAmount = vh.tvExpenseMoney.getText()
                            .toString();

                    Log.i("dateAmount", " " + expense.get(l).getAmount()
                            + " " + expense.get(l).getDate());

                    arrDateDebit.add(expense.get(l).getDate());
                    arrAmountDebit.add(expense.get(l).getAmount());

                    totalExpense += expense.get(l).getAmount();

                    DecimalFormat decimalFormatExpense = new DecimalFormat(
                            "0.#");
                    String finalTotalExpense = decimalFormatExpense
                            .format(Double.valueOf(totalExpense));
                    String valTvExpenseAmt = new BigDecimal(
                            finalTotalExpense).toPlainString();

                    vh.tvExpenseMoney.setText(String.format("%,.00f",
                            (double) Double.parseDouble(valTvExpenseAmt))
                            + " " + currencySymbl);

                    if (totalExpense == 0.0) {

                        vh.tvExpenseMoney.setText("0.0");
                        vh.tvMoneyCurrencyExpense.setText(currencySymbl);

                    } else {

                        if (vh.tvRecordnotFound.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            vh.tvRecordnotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            vh.tvMoneyCurrencyExpense
                                    .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            vh.tvExpenseMoney.setText(" " + totalExpense
                                    + " " + currencySymbl);

                            vh.tvMoneyCurrencyExpense
                                    .setText(currencySymbl);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    if (incomes.size() > 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < incomes.size(); j++) {

            Log.d("tagbankfil",
                    "" + bankNameForMatch + "=="
                            + incomes.get(j).getIncome_bankname() + " AND "
                            + incomes.get(j).getIncome_accno() + "=="
                            + bankAccNoForMatch);

            if (bankNameForMatch
                    .equals(incomes.get(j).getIncome_bankname())
                    && bankAccNoForMatch
                            .substring(bankAccNoForMatch.length() - 3)
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    incomes.get(j)
                                            .getIncome_accno()
                                            .substring(
                                                    incomes.get(j)
                                                            .getIncome_accno()
                                                            .length() - 3))) {

                dateIncome = incomes.get(j).getIncome_date();
                incomeAmount = incomes.get(j).getIncome_amount();

                Log.i("IncomeAmount", incomeAmount + ":::::" + dateIncome);

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                StringTokenizer tokensIncome = new StringTokenizer(
                        dateIncome, "-");

                String firstDate = tokensIncome.nextToken();
                String secondMonth = tokensIncome.nextToken();
                thirdYear = tokensIncome.nextToken();

                monthsInIntIncome = Integer.parseInt(thirdYear);

                int totalYear = Integer.parseInt(thirdYear);

                Log.i("MonthNameIncome", monthsInIntIncome + "  " + ""
                        + monthNameInStringIncome + " " + dateIncome + " "
                        + incomes.size() + "" + totalYear);

                Log.i("MonthSplitIncome", firstDate + "  " + secondMonth
                        + "  " + thirdYear);

                Log.i("loopTimes", "Check");

                SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "dd-MM-yyyy");

                Date dateVal = null;
                Log.i("axisbankdateval", dateVal + "");
                try {
                    dateVal = sdfSource.parse(dateIncome);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "dd-MMM-yyyy");

                convertDate = sdfDestination.format(dateVal);

                String[] parts = convertDate.split("-");
                String transactionMonth = parts[1];
                String transactionYear = parts[2];

                monthNameInStringIncome = getMonthName(transactionMonth);

                Log.i("finddate", convertDate + "::" + monthname + "::"
                        + monthNameInStringIncome);

                if (month.getMonth().contains(transactionMonth)
                        && totalYear == year) {

                    emptyIncomeAmount = vh.tvIncomeMoney.getText()
                            .toString();

                    arrDateCredit.add(incomes.get(j).getIncome_date());
                    arrAmountCredit.add(incomes.get(j).getIncome_amount());

                    totalIncome += incomes.get(j).getIncome_amount();

                    DecimalFormat decimalFormatIncome = new DecimalFormat(
                            "0.#");
                    String finalTotalIncome = decimalFormatIncome
                            .format(Double.valueOf(totalIncome));

                    String valTvIncomeAmt = new BigDecimal(finalTotalIncome)
                            .toPlainString();

                    vh.tvIncomeMoney.setText(String.format("%,.00f",
                            (double) Double.parseDouble(valTvIncomeAmt))
                            + " ");

                    vh.tvMoneyCurrencyIncome.setText(currencySymbl);

                    if (totalIncome == 0.0) {

                        vh.tvIncomeMoney.setText("0.0");
                        vh.tvMoneyCurrencyIncome.setText(currencySymbl);

                    } else {

                        if (vh.tvRecordnotFound.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            vh.tvRecordnotFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            vh.tvIncomeMoney.setText(" " + totalIncome
                                    + " " + currencySymbl);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.i("currentYear", year + "" + thirdYear);

    }

    CategoryList categoryListAdapter = new CategoryList(contextAddBank,
            arrDateDebit, arrAmountDebit, arrDateCredit, arrAmountCredit);

    vh.rvList.setAdapter(categoryListAdapter);
    setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(vh.rvList);
    vh.rvList.setScrollContainer(true);

    categoryListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return conView;
}
}
```

Comment: why not use expandable listview if you have list within list

Comment: can I create custom expandable listview?

Comment: yes you can. It is sort of similar to list view

Comment: Okay I will try if any solution not found in this.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is sticking when you're scrolling down because you're doing all of that processing upon every move when you scroll. Every row is running through the statements of your getView method every single time it's brought back to the screen, phones don't have enough processing power for all of that. You need to separate all of that into a different class, and then load it into the adapter in a smaller data set so that all it has to do is display it. Basically, you're doing processing in the UI(Main) thread, which is bad.

Given how you also have nested listViews, changing to an expandedListView would also be a lot easier for you in the grand scheme of things, may do the job better. Here's a tutorial for it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkazaAeeW1Q